# infinite while-loop not displaying cout

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char c;
    int value{}, value2{};
    while(true)
    {
        if(std::cin >> c)
        {
            if(c == '|') break;
            else continue;
            while(std::cin >> value >> value2)
            {
                std::cout << value << '\n' << value2 << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hello, I am trying to do here is take two integers as input in an infinite while-loop with a terminating char to exit the loop. Seems to work nice and dandy but then why is it that my output for my declarations isn't displaying? I am working through my reading material step-by-step to further my understanding, any help please greatly appreciated.

p.s

Further, I may try to make an exception to handle a minor detail, like using Z^ (ctrl+ Z) in my command line prompt window to exit as it's not accepting, thank you.

Comment: You never ever hit the inner while loop as you either `break` or `continue` before.

Comment: Do you know what `continue` does? It does not mean go to the next statement, it means, for a while loop, go to the start of the loop...

Comment: I would like to keep my break; as it allows me to terminate program successfully. I'm not sure how to implement any other way.

Comment: @ErickGuerrero Remove `else continue;`. It does not mean "keep going", it means "stop this iteration right here and continue with the next iteration".

Comment: I've progressed, but how may I stay in loop to keep accepting user input regardless if a char or int, either. My run-time doesn't want to further accept anymore char.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have

```
if(c == '|') break;
else continue;
```

in your code.
What this is doing is, if the value of c is equal to '|', the compiler gets outside the while loop and if value of c is not equal to '|', the compiler encounters continue, which makes it go back to the while (true) line.
The compiler never reaches the cout line.

Comment: Only further implication is that once I refactor, as I remove continue; any user input is not accepting char characters any longer. It kind of just hangs up there.

Comment: What input are you entering?
Also, you should remove the {} when declaring value1 and value2

Comment: I am trying to test my reasoning in this loop, my input is randomly arbitrary. I don’t mind what user inputs as long as iteration proceeds infinitely till determined by delimited char. I like using {} notation as a type-safety measure. Should I try with a normal ol’ regular declaration and initialization?

Comment: You should remove the second while loop and try something like this.
while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> c;
        if(c == '|') break;
        std::cin >> value >> value2;
        std::cout << value << '\n' << value2 << std::endl;
    }
You will input 3 values each time loop runs and if first value is '|', the loop ends.

Comment: One of my concerns, I only want program to accept two values and for this program not to rely on any work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

The nuance with C++ and working with parsing integers may cause some headaches as its implementation is quite specific. But here is some code that fulfills what I may have been requesting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int value[2];
    std::string text;


    while(std::cin >> c)
    {
            if(c == ',' || c == '|')
            {
                value[i] = std::stoi(text);
                text = "";
                i++;
                i = i%2;
                if(i==0)
                {
                    std::cout << value[0] << ' ' << value[1] << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                text = text + c;
            }
            if(c == '|') break;

    }

   return 0;
}
```

What needs to happen is a comma is required for parsing int values here.
I.E
User input: 123, (enter) 456,

There is also a way to implement without commas using getline. message for further details if curious.